# Using less-plugin-glob with Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to migrate the build system for an existing project from `gulp` to `webpack`.

It currently has a single entry point .less file which imports various other files as follows:

```
@import 'bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';
@import 'components/**/*.less';
```

This writes out a single css file which includes all of the .less files found. It uses https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob to allow globs.

Over in Webpack I have got as far as trying to use a combination of `less-loader`, `css-loader` and `style-loader` to achieve the same thing. The `modules` part of my webpack config looks like this:

```
var lessPluginGlob = require('less-plugin-glob');
...
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
      { loader: 'less-loader', options: { lessPlugins: [lessPluginGlob] }}
    ]
},
```

and I am trying to require my "entry" less file like so:

```
require('./app.less');
```

but no matter what I do I get this:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"importLoaders":1}!./~/less-loader?{"lessPlugins":[{}]}!./app/app.less
Module build failed: Can't resolve './components/**/*.less' in '/Users/matt/web-app/app'
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hey, I am having same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527423/webpack-import-multiple-less-files-using-glob-expressions. Have you figured out a solution so far?

Comment: I'm afraid not @Semih Gk. - in the end I just listed out the files and figured I'd come back to it later...

Comment: Thanks @Math Wilson . Well, I could not find a good solution so far, but I found a way at least. You may consider it unless you find better one. I post it below my question.

Answer (score 4):

I've made it work like this:

```
...
{
    loader: 'less-loader',
    options: {
        paths: [
            path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'app'))
        ],
        plugins: [
            require('less-plugin-glob')
        ]
    }
}
```

Check out the source code: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/blob/master/src/getOptions.js#L22

I don't know whether it's an intendend behaviour, but if `paths` is not specified  `createWebpackLessPlugin` being executed first, before `less-plugin-glob` plugin. And it throws an error since `createWebpackLessPlugin` knows nothing about next plugins.

So my solution was simply to specify `paths` to make `less-plugin-glob` being executed first.

Working example: https://github.com/notagency/webpack2-with-less-plugin-glob

Comment: This works for me, but any files I include with a glob seem to be unwatched by webpack (modifying does not trigger webpack to re-compile)

Comment: The watcher issue is noted here https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob/issues/23

Comment: You can use this plugin https://github.com/Fridus/webpack-watch-files-plugin as a temporary workaround.