# Webpack import multiple less files using glob expressions?

Tags: webpack, less, webpack-2

I have been trying to import less files automatically using webpack's less-loader, but glob expressions don't work in root.less file.

In detail, I am replacing gulp builder with webpack and I can use this pattern:

```
@import 'widgets/**/*.less';
```

to import less files in gulp automatically (Please check this link [glob expressions](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/425/automatic-import-of-lesssass-files-with-gulp)). However, this pattern is not valid in webpack and [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader) seems that do not support as well.

I tried to use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/) the method of webpack, but I cannot adjust the order or file imports. I need to require less files in a logical sequence because I use global variables(mixins, color codes etc). So, this option is not available as well.

```
import '../components/variables.less'; 
importAll(require.context('../components/', true, /\.less$/)); // Cannot set a sequence. 
// 'Variables' cannot be found even though I added it above
```

So, it seems I have to import each file manually which is really painful. That's why I wonder that is there any way to import files automatically?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `less-loader` [seems](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader#plugins) to support Less own plugins, so most likely you can use [`less-plugin-glob`](https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob) with it.

Comment: Thanks for response! Yeah, I already tried to use it, but it throws an error https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/issues/190 .

Comment: I found similar question here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629652/using-less-plugin-glob-with-webpack . I am having same issue actually.

Comment: *plugin.install is not a function* - it's the same error as [this](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists/issues/1). You're missing `new` there.

Comment: Well. I actually tried it, but it does not work at all. Even less-plugin-glob lib documentation doesn't create an instance of an object.

Comment: Hmm, you're right - looking at its sources I see it's already returning an object instead. Then sorry, I have o idea what can be wrong (it looks it was working just fine with `webpack` [before](https://github.com/Auxx/angular2-ts-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L75))

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. Yeah. I have seen that example as well. It seems it does work only with webpack 1, but I use webpack 2. Therefore, it throws an error ''configuration has an unknown property 'lessLoader''  which is not compatible with webpack config . In this stage, I cannot downgrade to webpack 1 since I need new features. I think I am gonna give up and I will import each file manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added `paths` option and it works:

```
...
{
    loader: 'less-loader',
    options: {
        paths: [
            path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'app'))
        ],
        plugins: [
            require('less-plugin-glob')
        ]
    }
}
```

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621947/2393499

Working example: https://github.com/notagency/webpack2-with-less-plugin-glob

Comment: Thank you for your response @Cold Shine, but you do not need to define 'paths' field in order to add a plugin. In the source code, '...clone(loaderUtils.getOptions(loaderContext)) ' fetches the plugins. However, I even tried to add paths option before, but it did not work. Secondly, could you share your webpack config and lib versions? I already spent a huge amount of time and I am pretty sure it does not work. Even if webpack works with this plugin(I had modified less loader plugin code), it throws an error when you define glob variables in less file.

Comment: @SemihGk. I've uploaded my simplified code to github https://github.com/notagency/webpack2-with-less-plugin-glob

Comment: @SemihGk Of course, you don't have to define `paths` to add plugins, but if `paths` is not defined `less-loader` initiate `createWebpackLessPlugin` before `less-plugin-glob`. And it throws an error at glob sentences like `@import 'widgets/**/*.less';` Check out the source here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/blob/master/src/getOptions.js#L22

Comment: Thank you very much for creating a sample code base. It's perfectly working. I tried on my project, but there is no luck somehow. Anyway, I will go through again when I have spare time. At least I could see the working version. Thanks again.

Comment: @SemihGk. Cool! Glad to help! :) Though this workaround could be version related...

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a proper solution for glob pattern paths, but I decided to create my entry less file dynamically. Anyone who encounter this issue may consider this solution:

```
   // update entry less file
var dir = require('node-dir');

function updateEntryLessFile() {
    dir.readFiles(path.resolve(__dirname, 'path-for-less-files-folder'), {
        match: /.less$/
    },
    (err, context, next) => { next() },
    (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'path-to-entry/entry.less')
        );
        _.each(files, path => {
            const relativePath = path.split('client/')[1]; // get relative path from full path
            wstream.write(`@import '~${relativePath}';\n`);
        });
        wstream.end();
    });
}

// When less files are added or removed, it updates entry.less file.
var watcher = require('chokidar').watch(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/'), {
  persistent: true,
  ignoreInitial: true
});

// Something to use when events are received.
var log = console.log.bind(console);
// Add event listeners.
watcher
  .on('add', path => {
      if (new RegExp('.less').test(path)) {
          log(`Less file: ${path} has been added`)
          updateEntryLessFile();
      }
  })
  .on('unlink', path => {
      if (new RegExp('.less').test(path)) {
          log(`Less file: ${path} has been removed`)
          updateEntryLessFile();
      }
  });

updateEntryLessFile();
```

So, you may run this before your webpack building or inside your webpack config would be fine.

If you find better way, please feel free to post it! Thanks.